# Three.js: rotate an object back and forth between two azimuth angles

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, azimuth

I have a 3D object loaded with three.js that should be seen only from the front since it is a single plane and from the back it is transparent ...

With the orbitContronls I limit the excursion of the azimuth and the polar angle ...

To make the 3D appealing it should start rotating ...

```
function animate() {
    if ( mesh ) {
        mesh.rotation.y += .005;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}
```

how do I limit the motion between -90° and 90° back and forth ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Math.sin()`

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    if ( mesh ) {
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.001) * Math.PI * 0.5;
    }

    render();
}
```

Comment: thank you, any reference so that I can improve my preparation, with your answer I just had to copy and paste and it works !!